# pyspark create new case statement variable within struct for each array element

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I want to create a new variable within each structure element of the array in this data frame. The new variable would be called 'statusrating' and would take each status string and map it to an integer. Status = "APPROVED" = 1, Status = "PENDING" = 0, Status = "REJECTED" = -1.  I assume this requires a CASE WHEN statement but I haven't been able to figure it out. Could someone help me with the correct code?

Current df:

```
form_info:array
|   element:struct
|   |    id :string
|   |    status:string
```

Desired df:

```
form_info:array
|   element:struct
|   |    id :string
|   |    status:string
|   |    statusrating:integer
```

Comment: the solution i've stated works on struct columns only. but i see that the schema states it is an array of structs. in that case, you'd need to use `transform()` function. it's be helpful if you share a few example records from your current df.

Comment: [{"ID": "12345667",  "STATUS": "APPROVED"}, {"ID": "1789083",  "STATUS": "PENDING"}]

Comment: @ChristianneGreer 
kindly share sample data with schema and output with example so that question will be more clear to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spark 3.1+, you can use [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html) to add a new field within an existing struct.

```python
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_struct',
               func.when(func.col('old_struct.status') == 'APPROVED', 
                         func.col('old_struct').withField('statusrating', func.lit(1))
                         ).
               when(func.col('old_struct.status') == 'PENDING', 
                    func.col('old_struct').withField('statusrating', func.lit(0))
                    ).
               when(func.col('old_struct.status') == 'REJECTED', 
                    func.col('old_struct').withField('statusrating', func.lit(-1))
                    )
               )
```

If `withField` is unavailable, you'd need to recreate the whole struct.

```python
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_struct',
               func.when(func.col('old_struct.status') == 'APPROVED', 
                         func.expr('struct(old_struct.*, 1 as statusrating)')
                         ).
               when(func.col('old_struct.status') == 'PENDING', 
                    func.expr('struct(old_struct.*, 0 as statusrating)')
                    ).
               when(func.col('old_struct.status') == 'REJECTED', 
                    func.expr('struct(old_struct.*, -1 as statusrating)')
                    )
               )
```

Based on the example row shared in the question comments, you have an array of structs and would need to use `transform`.

Given the input data as following array of structs with `id` and `status` as struct fields.

```python
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |form_info                                                      |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{12345667, APPROVED}, {1789083, PENDING}, {1789876, REJECTED}]|
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You'll use `transform` to update the values within an array

```python
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('form_info_updated',
               func.expr('''transform(form_info, x -> if(x.status = "APPROVED", struct(x.id, x.status, 1 as statusrating),
                                                         if(x.status = "PENDING", struct(x.id, x.status, 0 as statusrating),
                                                            if(x.status = "REJECTED", struct(x.id, x.status, -1 as statusrating), struct(x.id, x.status, null as statusrating))
                                                            )
                                                         )
                                      )
                         ''')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |form_info                                                      |form_info_updated                                                        |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{12345667, APPROVED}, {1789083, PENDING}, {1789876, REJECTED}]|[{12345667, APPROVED, 1}, {1789083, PENDING, 0}, {1789876, REJECTED, -1}]|
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm getting a "'Column' object is not callable" error with both of these.

Comment: as stated in my question comment, both of them would work if your column is a struct column - NOT array of structs -- @ChristianneGreer

Comment: @ChristianneGreer updated answer for array of structs

Answer (score 1):

didn't notice this was in pyspark, but I'll post this anyways in case someone finds this solution useful in scala.

In this scenario, I would use Dataset and a mapping function. I think it would be a clean solution and scales well if you have many case matches.

```
  import spark.implicits._

  case class Form(form_info: String, element: Array[Status])

  case class Status(id: String, status: String)

  case class NewForm(form_info: String, element: Array[NewStatus])

  case class NewStatus(id: String, status: String, statusInt: Int)

  val ds = Seq(
    Form("Form1", Array(
      Status("id1", "APPROVED"),
      Status("id2", "PENDING"),
      Status("id3", "REJECTED")
    )),
  ).toDS()

  def mapStatusToInt(status: String): Int = {
    status match {
      case "APPROVED" => 1
      case "PENDING" => 0
      case "REJECTED" => -1
    }
  }

  val newDs = ds.map {
    form: Form => {
      NewForm(form.form_info, form.element.map(
        status => NewStatus(status.id, status.status, mapStatusToInt(status.status))
      ))
    }
  }

  newDs.printSchema()
  newDs.show(false)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- form_info: string (nullable = true)
 |-- element: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statusInt: integer (nullable = false)

+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|form_info|element                                                     |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|Form1    |[{id1, APPROVED, 1}, {id2, PENDING, 0}, {id3, REJECTED, -1}]|
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I think it should be possible to apply a similar solution in pyspark using Dataframe.map, I will update the answer in case I figure it out.

Hope this is helpful in the offchance that you can use scala.